# Query to get records from 3 object relationship

Tags: soql

**Setup**

- I have three objects: `X`, `Y`, and `Z`.
- `X` (child) has master-detail relationship to `Y` (parent).
- `Z` (child) has a lookup relationship to `Y` (parent).

**Question**

How do I retrieve records from object `X` which are also related to object `Z` with `Y`? That is, results from `X` having common entry in `Y`.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Are you looking for `X` records whose `Y` has *any* child `Z` records? Or you already have some `Z` records and you are looking for `X` records that look up to their `Y` parents? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Question, does your "X" have a lookup to "Z"? because you mentioned "X which are also related to object Z with Y"

Comment: If `Z` is a (lookup) child of `Y` and `Y` is a (detail) child of `X`, then to traverse from X to Z requires two SOQL queries (X + Ys) and (Ys + Zs)

Comment: Can you also clarify what object is master and which child in each relationship?

Comment: @crop1645 Pretty sure `X` is also a child of `Y`.

Answer (score 4):

For simplicity I will rename your objects to:

- `X` => `Detail`
- `Y` => `Parent`
- `Z` => `Child`

---

The most reasonable interpretation of your OP I can infer is:

> If I have a collection of `Child` records, how can I find `Detail` records for the same `Parent` records?

If this interpretation is correct, you can do the following:

```
public static List<Detail__c> findSiblings(List<Child__c> children)
{
    Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Child__c child : children) parentIds.add(child.Parent__c);
    return [SELECT Id FROM Detail__c WHERE Parent__c IN :parentIds];
}
```

---

Another interpretation I could see is:

> How can I find all `Detail` records whose `Parent` has any `Child` records?

If this interpretation is correct, I would add a field on `Parent` along the lines of `Has_Child_Records__c`, which you can manage from `Process Builder`. Just set it up on `Child` to update the `Parent` checkbox with the criteria `OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED(Parent__c))`. Then you can just do:

```
public static List<Detail__c> findDetails()
{
    return [SELECT Id FROM Detail__c WHERE Parent__r.Has_Child_Records__c = true];
}
```

If neither of these interpretations is correct, please add more detail to your question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You could query the parent and subquery the children, you can run this example in the Developer console, just change the Account Name filter, to see the results:

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Name FROM Opportunities), (SELECT Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Name = 'sForce'
```

To Adrians point if you wanted only parents that had both types of children you could do semi-joins like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Name FROM Opportunities), (SELECT Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Name = 'sForce' 
AND Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE FirstName = 'Jake') AND Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity)
```

Or just one of the children types like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Name FROM Opportunities), (SELECT Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Name = 'sForce' 
AND Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE FirstName = 'Jake')
```